# Авторизация в java веб-приложении

Tags: авторизация, java

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь в простом веб-приложении под `Apache Tomcat` настроить `forms` авторизацию.
Для этого в web.xml прописал:

```
<login-config>
   <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
   <realm-name>default</realm-name>
     <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Default Security Constraints</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>test</web-resource-name>         
                   <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
                 <http-method>GET</http-method>         
             <http-method>POST</http-method> 
         </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint/>
    </security-constraint>
```

Вроде запретил доступ ко всем ресурсам, но  index.html в корне приложения test всё равно открывается. Как сделать чтобы был редирект на login.html, если пользователь ещё не авторизовался? 
И следующий вопрос: как программно разрешить доступ к ресурсам приложения через Servlet к которому будет отправляться ajax запрос с login.html ?

Comment: вот примет [тут][1] 


  [1]: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-form-authentication-with-tomcat.html?page=1

Comment: Всё хорошо, только совсем непонятно, как разрешить доступ к странице после авторизации в своём Servlet ?